# Delphi Prism: Does BinaryWriter "Write method" work the same as Writeln method from Delphi?

Tags: .net, delphi, delphi-prism, binaryreader, binarywriter

I am working with Delphi Prism and creating and writing into binary file using BinaryWriter as follows.

```
method TUnit.Write(bw:BinaryWriter);
var
    i:Integer;
begin
    bw.write(ord(uType));
    bw.Write(ord(State));
    bw.Write(Address);
    bw.Write(SubAddress);

    for i:=1 to 20 do
        bw.Write(fDefs[i]);
end;
```

My question to you is this. Does the write method write line per line or bytes after bytes or character after character without line feed or carriage return?

The reason I am asking this question is because I am confused when it comes to writing and reading string without specific numbers of characters like array of characters.

For instance:

```
method WritetoFile;
var
    x:integer;
    thestr:string;
begin
    BinaryWriter thefile := new BinaryWriter(File.Create("test.dat"));
    thefile.write(thestr);
    thefile.write(x);
    thefile.Close;
end;

method ReadFromFile;
var
   x:integer;
   thestr:string;
begin
   BinaryReader thefile := new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("test.dat"));
   thestr:=thefile.ReadString;
   x:=thefile.ReadInt32;
   thefile.Close;
end;
```

That's how I wrote my program and it seems to work fine, but as I said I am confused.

How does it know how many bytes or characters length to read or write when it is a string data type without giving it a specific numbers of length to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does BinaryWriter "Write method" work the same as Writeln method from Delphi?

No it does not.

> How does it know how many bytes or characters length to read or write when it is a string data type without giving it a specific numbers of length to read?

In many ways you don't really need to know how `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` does it. You are using it correctly. You just need to pair each `Write()` call with a matching `ReadXXX()` call of the appropriate type.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx) does describe the underlying binary file format. You don't need to write or read the length of the string since the Binary I/O classes do exactly that on your behalf.

> A length-prefixed string represents the string length by prefixing to the string a single byte or word that contains the length of that string. This method first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer, and then writes that many characters to the stream by using the BinaryWriter instance's current encoding.

So you can safely write a string which contains linefeeds and when it is read those linefeeds will be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. You want to use StreamWriter for that, which has WriteLine and Write methods that do what you want. The binaryReader/Writer classes use a prefix integer for the Length, then write the data.

Comment: Actually, it looks to me more like @digitalanalog wants what BinaryWriter does than a text writer.